# Next greater element using recursion

Tags: recursion, stack

I have seen the problem of finding the next greater element for each element in an array and it can be easily solved using monotonic stack. But can it be solved using recursion?

For the input array [4, 5, 2, 25], the next greater elements for each element are as follows.

```
   4      -->   5           
   5      -->   25        
   2      -->   25       
   25     -->   -1
```

Using stack

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void printNGE(int arr[], int n)
{
    stack<int> s;
    int res[n];
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    
        if (!s.empty()) {
            while (!s.empty() && s.top() <= arr[i]) {
                s.pop();
            }
        }
        res[i] = s.empty() ? -1 : s.top();
        s.push(arr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " --> " << res[i] << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 11, 13, 21, 3 };
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    printNGE(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long long fun(long long i,vector<long long>&v,long long par)
    {
        if(i==v.size())
        return -1;
        if(v[i]>v[par])
        {
            return v[i];
        }
        return fun(i+1,v,par);
    }
    
    void solve(long long i,vector<long long>&v,vector<long long>&ans)
    {
        if(i==v.size())return ;
        solve(i+1,v,ans);
        long long temp=fun(i+1,v,i);
        ans[i]=temp;
    }
    vector<long long> nextLargerElement(vector<long long> v, int n)
    {
        vector<long long>ans(n,-1);
        solve(0,v,ans);
        return ans;
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).